# Tellraw command “not reading the t!”

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried to enter this command:

```
/tellraw @a Herobrine joined the game
```

But the error message says ”Unknown command ellraw”

So it seems as if it is not reading the t!
`/tp` is working

```
/ tellraw @a Herobrine joined the game
```

is not working

Why is the game not reading the t in the tellraw command?

I am playing on Windows 10 ( bedrock edition)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: The command should look like this: `/tellraw @a { "rawtext":[{"text":"Herobrine joined the game"}]}`

Comment: I am playing on bedrock where there are no NBT tags

Comment: I can not post screenshots

Comment: @Abraham Use the command provided anyway. This is not NBT, it's JSON, and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the `t` isn't there is that the problem is "`Herobrine`" because you didn't use JSON format. If you check the error message you can see that the end was cut off as well:

[image: error message]

The correct way is to use JSON which would be like this:

```
/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"Herobrine joined the game"}]}
```